# Only print row columns if column name matches variable

Tags: php, mysql

I have a script that produces a table from a mysql result and I'm aiming to make the columns displayed fully dynamic based on a variable which contains the names of the columns I want displayed. I am already producing the table headings this way with this code:

```
$search_field_names=explode(',', $search_field_names)    
for($i=0, $count=count($search_field_names);$i<$count;$i++) {
        echo ('<th>'.$search_field_names[$i].'</th>');
    }
```

Where $search_field_names is a comma separatated string of values (like eg. fristname,lastname,user_id etc.).

To make an example, let's say the string above contains 7 names of columns I want to display like this:

```
$search_field_names=('firstname,lastname,dob,company,position,user_id,date_added')
```

The first code snippet would then produce a table heading with those 7 names.

And then comes the tricky part: The database table where all the records are stored have a total of 22 columns. By doing the exact same thing as the first snippet to print out the records, the result would be that it prints the first 7 columns from that table, which isn't necessarily the ones I want.

Here is how I get the records (this abviously comes after the above snippets in the script):

```
$query=mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM table WHERE column_name1='$search_query' AND column_name2='$search_query' etc...);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
echo('<tr>');
for($i=0, $count=count($search_field_names);$i<$count;$i++) {
        echo ('<td>'.$row[$i].'</td>');
    }
echo('</tr>');
```

So, what I want to achieve is to only fetch the columns in the database, which correspons to the names set in the variable $search_field_names.

Comment: Why don;t you change your Select query and get only the columns available in your $Search_field_names variable?

Comment: Because each user of my webpage has data stored in different columns of the databse, so the query searches all the columns. But, as you mention it, is it possible to make a similar for() loop within the search query, so it only searches the columns stored in the variable? If that's possible It would probably solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Two solutions, as suggested by Haider, use your $search_field_names variable to adapt your query :

```
$query=mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT ".implode(",", $search_field_names)." FROM table");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    echo('<tr>');
    for($i=0, $count=count($search_field_names);$i<$count;$i++) {
        echo ('<td>'.$row[$i].'</td>');
    }
    echo('</tr>');
}
```

Or, since you're doing a mysqli_fetch_assoc, this should work :

```
$query=mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM table");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    echo('<tr>');
    for($i=0, $count=count($search_field_names);$i<$count;$i++) {
        // Using header name as the key to the column
        echo ('<td>'.$row[ $search_field_names[$i] ].'</td>');
    }
    echo('</tr>');
}
```

EDIT : so far, we've only looked at cleverly looping through $search_field_names to generate the table of results. You asked in your last comment if we could use the same trick when building the constraints of the query. One problem is, you *seem* to want to use $_POST directly in your query. Please don't do this, this is a source of [SQL injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Another problem is, we can't be clever forever. We can do this if all the fields are of the same type, but if one of your search fields is a date or an integer, it's going to get really hard to write and debug.

So, if you really *have* to be clever with your query, you could do something like this (assuming ALL search fields are string values) :

```
<?php
// Assuming you have a $post_array like so, where inputs have the same names as the column names in the database
// $post_array = array('username' => 'T', 'url' => 'http');

// Build constraints of the form column_name LIKE 'value%'
$constraints = array();
foreach ($post_array as $key => $value) {
    $constraints[] = "$key LIKE ?";
    $post_array[$key] = $value.'%';
}

// Build a query selecting the columns from $post_array, with corresponding constraints
// Note : replace " AND " by " OR " if you want the query to match ANY parameter.
$query_text = "SELECT ".implode(", ", array_keys($post_array))." FROM table WHERE ".implode(" AND ", $constraints);

// Prepare this query, we don't want SQL injections!
$query = $mysqli->prepare($query_text);

$bind = array();
foreach ($post_array as $key => $value) {
    // We need to use our bind variables outside the scope of this loop, so we create them in $GLOBALS
    $GLOBALS[$key] = $value;
    // Array of references to our bind variables.
    $bind[] = &$$key;
}
// Binding the parameters : we need as many 's' as there are inputs
$bindtypes = str_repeat('s', count($post_array))
call_user_func_array(array($query, 'bind_param'), array_merge( array($bindtypes), $bind ));
// Binding the retrieved columns
echo call_user_func_array(array($query, 'bind_result'), $bind);
$query->execute();

// Header row
echo '<tr>';
foreach ($post_array as $key => $value) {
    echo '<th>'.$key.'</th>';
}
echo '</tr>';

// Result rows
while ($query->fetch()) {
    echo('<tr>');
    foreach ($post_array as $key => $value) {
        echo '<td>', $$key, '</td>';
    }
    echo('</tr>');
}
?>
```

Comment: Yeah, that's a likely solution, however I forgot to include in my original question that the query is SELECT .. FROM table WHERE column_name='$search_query'.

Comment: I don't understand this query. What's in the `$search_query` variable? What do you mean by `column_name`?

Comment: $search_query is a POST variable from an input field
column_name was just an example. A real world example would be:
SELECT .. FROM table WHERE firstname LIKE '$search_query%' AND lastname LIKE '$search_query$' etc.

Comment: Hm. I tried to implement the solution, but encountered some errors, one being that it added an extra , after the last imploded variable in the SELECT <here>. There was also some issues with the bind arrays which didn't match up. Very grateful for your time, but I'm on a tight schedule for getting this up and runnig, but I will continue working on this at a later time. Thank you!

Also, my table does indeed contain a mix of varchar, datetime and integer columns so I guess I'll just have to fall back on my old, working solution which prints out each searchable field as it's own input field.